# How to Show and Hide video during Pjsua2 video call in Android?

Tags: android, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I am working on an android video call using Pjsua2 pjsip library. I got the video call working. How can i create a disable and enable back video during the call with just a click function during the call.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `VideoWindow.Show(true)` to show to show the video in C#， I don't no if it is ok for android